# Add dependency to remote spark on intelliJ

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running spark in intelliJ remotely but facing difficulties while adding dependency to spark conf.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("spark://IP:7077")
    .set("packages", "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1:jar")
    .setAppName("localtrial")
```

Error:

> 16/02/23 12:27:10 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 172.16.248.156): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation$$anonfun$buildScan$1$$anonfun$3
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ```

I have also tried setJars property of conf class. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the dependency to your `build.sbt` file so that IntelliJ can compile against it.  If you are adding it as an argument to `spark-submit` then you can set the dependency as `prodived` else you need to package it inside your jar file by using the sbt-assembly, or similar, plugin.

Add the following line to your `build.sbt` file and if auto-import is enabled Intellij will download the dependency.  If auto-import isn't enabled close the project and import it again or use the refresh button inside the SBT tool window.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "2.0.1" % "provided"
```